# Simple inline diff algorithm that adds <ins> <del> tags for use with PHP and HTML?

Tags: php, diff

I've tried [Paul's Simple Diff Algorithm](http://compsci.ca/v3/viewtopic.php?t=15705) before but it works terribly. It even can't show that only few characters were added at the end of the string without marking that allegedly some of this string was deleted.

I need something like this:

```
string end
begin strngs
<ins>begin </ins>str<del>i</del>ng<ins>s</ins><del> end</del>
```

Comment: I would like to have the stackoverflow diff algo for this! Anyway if you search other questions have been answered but none of the answers provided were something good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried http://www.raymondhill.net/finediff/viewdiff-ex.php and the result is exactly what you want, if you select 'character' granularity.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that a good diff algorithm is largely based on heuristics. It depends on what kind of changes you have and how you would like to represent them.

For instance:

```
The cat jumped over the fence
The panther jumped over the fence
```

You could diff as:

```
The <del>c</del><ins>p</ins>a<ins>n</ins>t<ins>her</ins> jumped over the fence
```

or:

```
The <del>cat</del><ins>panther</ins> jumped over the fence
```

Both are accurate (omiting any mistakes on my part).

Comment: It doesn't have to be bullet proof. That alg could have a fail save flag that says the changes are so complicated that I give up, so then heavier artillery could be used.

Comment: It's never too hard to diff. If there would a 'too hard' criteria it would be part of said heuristic.

Comment: if you a php scirpt that does like your second example post it!